# How to check the type of an element in a 2d array in Python

Tags: python, list

I've been trying to make a tic-tac-toe game and so far, I've only created a function that's supposed to print out the board:

```
    board = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

    def drawboard(board):
        for row in board:
            for item in row:
                if type(board[row][item]) == "int":
                    print(str(board[row][item]))
                    print("|")
                else:
                    print(board[row][item])
                    print("|")
            print("\n")
            print("------")
            print("\n")

    drawboard(board)
```

As you can see, a part of my function is checking the type of an element inside of a list inside of a list but it's giving me an error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/Users/Tony/Desktop/coding
>   things/tic tac toe.py", line 22, in 
>       drawboard(board)\   File "/Users/Tony/Desktop/coding things/tic tac toe.py", line 12, in drawboard
>       if type(board[row][item]) == "list": TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list

Comment: `board = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]` is *not an array*, it is a `list` object.

Comment: `type(board[row][item])`   replace it with `type(item)`

Comment: Also, this is not Javascript. the `type(obj)` function *returns the actual type of `obj`, and in Python, a type (i.e. a class) is *just another kind of object). So you'd use `type(obj) is int` for example. Although often you should use `isinstance(ob, int)` if you want to include subclasses

Comment: `board[row][item]` should be only `item`

Comment: `row` and `item` aren't indices, you only need to check type of `item` instead of `board[row][item]`

Answer (score 1):

In your for loops, `row` and `item` aren't indices, you only need to check the type of `item`, to do that you need to change this line:

```
if type(board[row][item]) == "int":
```

to

```
if isinstance(item, int):
```

After fix:

```
def drawboard(board):
    for row in board:
        for item in row:
            if isinstance(item, int):
                print(str(item))
                print("|")
            else:
                print(item)
                print("|")
        print("\n")
        print("------")
        print("\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems here:

1. if you iterate over a list, you iterate over the *elements* of the list, *not* the *indices*; and
2. if you query for `type(..)` you do *not* get a string as return element, but a reference to the class. So you can fix this like:

```
    board = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

    def drawboard(board):
        for row in board:
            for item in row:
                if type(item) == int:
                    print(str(item))
                    print("|")
                else:
                    print(item)
                    print("|")
            print("\n")
            print("------")
            print("\n")

    drawboard(board)
```

Since non-`str` items are typically `str(..)`-ed when you call print on them, we can even merge the `if` and `else` branch into:

```
def drawboard(board):
    for row in board:
        for item in row:
            print(item)
            print("|")
        print("\n")
        print("------")
        print("\n")

drawboard(board)
```

If you proceed with this typecheck, typically checking for type equality is not really a good idea either. Since if the element is subclassed, the type is no longer `int`. You then better use `isinstance(..)`.

Comment: so `print(str(item))` => `print(item)`